# Display a database table in a jqGrid

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, jqgrid

I'm desperately trying to display the data from my database inside a jqGrid I created, but I don't really understand how it works.

I read thoroughly the documentation about jqGrid and tried to adapt the demos of the official website but I can't find a simple way to just replace the "data" option of the grid with a PHP/MySQL or AJAX script. Here is my code:

```
    <script>
        $(function (){
            $("#grid").jqGrid({
                colNames: ["ID", "Context", "IP", "Community", "Modèle", "Uptime", "Version Soft", "Version Patch", "Date d'ajout", "Date modif", "Refresh"],
                colModel: [
                    {name:'id', index:'id', width:60, sorttype:'int', align:'center'},
                    {name:'context', index:'context', width:130, align:'center'},
                    {name:'ip', index:'ip', width:150, align:'center'},
                    {name:'community', index:'community', width:100, align:'center'},
                    {name:'modele', index:'modele', width:80, align:'center'},
                    {name:'uptime', index:'uptime', width:150, align:'center'},
                    {name:'soft', index:'soft', width:150, align:'center'},
                    {name:'patch', index:'patch', width:150, align:'center'},
                    {name:'ajout', index:'ajout', width:100, sorttype:'date', align:'center'},
                    {name:'modif', index:'modif', width:100, sorttype:'date', align:'center'},
                    {name:'refresh', index:'refresh', width:70, align:'center', formatter:refresh_Button}
                ],
                data: [
                    {id:"1",context:"LAB",ip:"192.168.xx.xx",community:"public",modele:"S57",ajout:"20-11-2017"}
                ],
                caption: "Equipements disponibles :",
                sortname: 'id',
                sortorder:"desc",
                rowNum:20,
                rowList:[20,40,60],
                pager:'#yolo'
            });
            function refresh_Button(cellvalue, options, rowobject){
                return '<button type="button" onclick="">Go</button>';

            }

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="yolo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to do something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case people want to know the answer, you have to :

1. add these parameters in your jqGrid options :

> url:"*your_ajax_page.php*"
>
> mtype:"POST" //or GET
>
> datatype:"json"
>
> loadonce:"true"

2. create *your_ajax_page.php* and basically copy the "loadonce" demo on the official jqGrid demo website (which is currently down).
3. after you have linked your database data and your jqGrid rows, add "*echo json_encode($data_array)*" at the bottom of the page
4. This should be it, hope it helped you